# Can a Monk who has multi-classed to Cleric use holy symbols?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

Can a Monk who has multi-classed with `Initiate of the Faith` to Cleric use holy symbols as an implement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

> In addition you can use holy symbols as an implement

Thus yes, he can use holy symbols as an implement for any power with the `Implement` key word.